# Calling Oracle stored procedure from batch script

Tags: oracle, batch-file

I want to execute a stored procedure from a Windows script I have to create
just a simple call to an Oracle db stored procedure already in the database.

I tried using `sqlcmd` to call the stored procedure, but I get the error that `sqlcmd` is not a recognised command. Any leads would be much appreciated and helpful.

Comment: `sqlcmd` is the **SQL Server** command line tool - it's not compatible with Oracle

Comment: tx, any suggestions how to go about this?

Comment: I would imagine Oracle has something similar to `sqlcmd` - just read the docs and find it ..... I'm not an Oracle developer/user of any kind ...

Comment: tx I'll research on it

Comment: Oracle has `sqlplus` which is part of the Oracle client.  Or `sqlcl` (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html) which is part of SQL Developer.